# HighCharts/HighStocks not scrolling on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[image: overthrow-polyfill.js error]

Hi, particulary I am having a problem with HighCharts / HighStock not scrolling on the x-axis to display hidden data such as the times contained here:

[image: Time]

It works just fine in Chrome browser on my Desktop. Whenever I scroll the overthrow-polyfill.js error shows itself. This is not a library I included myself as I can't find any mention of overthrow in all my code.

Sidenote: I do have angular touch and fastclick in the mix as well, but removing them did not help either

Comment: I must mention going back that the error happens `onmousedown`. Might not even have anything to do with the swipe not working, I think.

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle.net.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6kfo6wae/1/ It is in no way complete. This is is a massive project and I'm not expecting this link will give me much help, but I'm hoping the issue is there perhaps

Comment: Well, your fiddle contains many custom lines and additionaolly references to scope which is not defined. So how we can recreate your issue? Could you prepare minified demo with hardcoded values only for introudce problem ?

Comment: Hi, I would be able to give you a chart with data, but as far as making it not work I don't know how I would be able to achieve that from scratch because there are lots of libraries in the code and I am maintaining legacy code. Seems that HighCharts is conflicting with that code when it comes to touch. Thanks for your consideration though.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem on mobile device. After couple of hour i have found that scrolling is available just on mousemove event, but not on touch event. To fix this I have added the same listeners on touch events.

```
Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.onContainerTouchStart = Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.onContainerMouseDown;
var onContainerMouseMove = Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.onContainerMouseMove;
Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.onContainerTouchMove = function(e) {
    onContainerMouseMove.call(this, e);
    if ("touchstart" === this.chart.mouseIsDown) {
        this.drag(e);
    }
};
```